# Stack Overflow style keyword tags

Tags: autocomplete, tags, keyword

I am creating a Ruby on Rails application and I want to replicate the Stack Overflow 'Tags' input box that you use when posting a question. After you type out a word or phrase it becomes a box with an 'x' next to it allowing you to delete it: [image]

Does anyone know whether I can implement this feature in a Rail app?

Comment: Of course. Nothing to do with Rails, all about the JS. JQuery plugins exist. Only part that concerns Rails is associating tags with your models.

Comment: There is a RailsCast on it: http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields

Answer (score 3):

There is a jQuery plugin for this called tokenInput, which can be found here: http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/

All you need to be able to do is send it a list of words in json format, so that can easily be done in RoR.